# Android HtmlCompat.toHtml(Spanned) returns improperly nested HTML tags

Tags: android, html, android-edittext, fromhtml

I have an Edittext (binding.text using view binding) that contains text styled with StyleSpans, i.e. bold and italics. To save the formatted text, I use HtmlCompat.toHtml(spannable) in Kotlin to convert it into HTML.

```
var htmlString = HtmlCompat.toHtml(SpannableString(binding.text.text), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

However, the HTML returned is improperly nested if the text has bold and italics applied to it at the same time.

- ***Hello World***: outputs `<p dir="ltr><b><i>Hello world</b></i></p>`

As you can see, the tags applied are `<b><i> </b></i>` instead of `<b><i> </i></b>`.

---

When the text is not formatted, or either in bold or italics, then proper HTML is returned:

- Hello World: outputs `<p dir="ltr>Hello world</p>`
- **Hello World**: outputs `<p dir="ltr><b>Hello world</b></p>`

---

I suppose the function likes to put `<b>` and `</b>` first as opposed to `<i>` and `</i>`, but this causes weird results as shown.
So the question: How do I get the function to return correctly formatted HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the ordering, although the HTML should still display correctly in a browser. The offending code is in *Html.java*. Here is where the translations occur for `<b></b>` and `<i></i>`:

```
...
for (int j = 0; j < style.length; j++) {    
    ...
    if (style[j] instanceof StyleSpan) {
        int s = ((StyleSpan) style[j]).getStyle();
    
        if ((s & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            out.append("<b>");
        }
        if ((s & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            out.append("<i>");
        }
    }

...
for (int j = style.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    ,,,
    if (style[j] instanceof StyleSpan) {
        int s = ((StyleSpan) style[j]).getStyle();
    
        if ((s & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            out.append("</b>");
        }
        if ((s & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            out.append("</i>");
        }
    }
```

`style` is an array of spans. This code scans forward through the spans to place the opening tags and backward to close the tags. So, it looks like if your bold span and italic spans are different spans spanning the same text, then this code will produce properly nested tags.

However, if one *StyleSpan* specifies both italic and bold, then the tag order will be as you report `<b><i></b></i>`. The code that outputs the closing tags should place `<i>` before `b`. This looks like a bug and should be reported.

I assume that you have one *StyleSpan* that is a bolded-italics span. The fix would be to split that span into two separate spans - a bold span and an italics span. The code should then work as expected.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened! I was using a bolded-italics span as I thought it was cleaner than two separate spans, but now I know better. Thanks a lot for your guidance :)

Comment: @TongJingYen What you did should be OK and is what I would have done. This is a bug in the _Html.java_ code. I am going to report it and link to this post.

Comment: @TongJingYen Here is the [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187246528).

Comment: Thanks for the report. Is it okay for me to add a screenshot as a comment in it?

Comment: @TongJingYen I think that would be OK.